# ViewModels with Hilt

Tags: android, retrofit, android-room, dagger-hilt

I'd like to learn write clean code, so I've decided to ask you for a hint. Let's say we have an app, which uses:

-retrofit/live data

-room/flows

The app, also have a few fragments, let's say 5. Before I've started with learning hilt, I was using single ViewModel, for each fragment. Now, when hilt make thing easier, and there's less code, I'd like to know, if I should stay with ViewModel for each fragment, or should I use let's say one ViewModel?

Answer (score 0):

Well,For this its totally depends upon your project and scalability if you have short project you can have common ViewModel....but I personally dont prefer do that because code readability must be easier ....every fragment have own use case  and functionality so I prefer to make new one util unless if your functionality is same you reuse the viewModel by Injecting them.

I hope you will understand...

Thankyou!! Happy Coding!!

Answer (score 0):

The best recommendation would be to create separate viewModel for all Fragments as it will help you in logic separation and also it will be easier to debug too.

Also the purpose of MVVM is to have a viewmodel for all lifecyleOwners, and Fragment is also lifecyleOwners thus it is highly recommended to go with seperate viewModel.

And since you have mentioned HILT, it will be very easy to setup the ViewModel dependencies and I would also recommend to use delegates to initialise the viewmodel that will further simplifies the code. To usage of delegates are :

Firstly You need to add these 2 dependencies

```
implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:$activity_version"
implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:$fragment_version"
```

Then just use the delegates to lazy initialise the viewModel

```
val mViewModel by viewModels<MuCustomViewModel>()
```

This will remove you overhead to initialise the viewModel manually.
Hope this will help you!

Thanks and Keep Coding....

Answer (score 0):

You should have a view model for each **model** and **view** combination. Most likely the view is a Fragment, but it doesn't have to be. Also, if you are using more than one model in a view, then you might have multiple view models in a single Fragment.